# Can I force Codename One's InfiniteScrollAdapter not to loop

Tags: codenameone

My app features an `InfiniteScrollAdapter` because it looks good and is advised in the [doc](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/avoiding-lists.html). However, I don't want the "list" to loop back from the beginning when it reaches the end (otherwise the user can think there are many entries although they are just duplicated).

Is the solution to set the value of `InfiniteScrollAdapter.setComponentLimit()` to the number of entries ? Or should I use a container in Y `BoxLayout` (will the data still be fetched as lazily as with the `InfiniteScrollAdapter`?)

Comment: Always accept and upvote or comment on answers to acknowledge it helps you or you need more clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My method is to keep track of the `lastId` and number of records returned.

Let's take for instance I have a database with 105 records and I want to fetch them 10 at a time:

I will make sure the query pulls the records in ascending or descending orders.

Let's say it's in ascending order, my initial `lastId` will be 0 and once records are returned the `lastId` will change to the last record id (In this case 10). Then I pass that as a parameter to pull next records where id is greater than the `lastId` (10), that's 11 upward.

Coding idea:

```
InfiniteScrollAdapter.createInfiniteScroll(scroller, new Runnable() {
    private int pageNumber = 0;
    private int lastId = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //Go fetch records with lastId as parameter

            if (records != null) {
                //create components array from records and add them as required

                lastId = id value of the last record returned

                pageNumber++; //increment this to indicate this is not first run.
                //Here we set the boolean value to see if records returned is at least 10. If it is, it means we have more records to pull from the database, else it's the last batch (In our case, record 91 to 95 is less than 10 and it's the last batch) 
                InfiniteScrollAdapter.addMoreComponents(myContainer, componentsToAdd, records.size() >= 10);
            } else {
                //show an error message if pageNumber == 1 (First run), otherwise remove the infinite scroll adapter
            myContainer.getComponentAt(myContainer.getComponentCount() - 1).remove();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //show an error message if pageNumber == 1 (First run), otherwise remove the infinite scroll adapter
            myContainer.getComponentAt(myContainer.getComponentCount() - 1).remove();
        }
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: Thanks @Diamond and sorry for the late reply! Your answer addresses the lazyness part of my question, doesn't it ? I'll have a deeper look at it later when my head has stopped overheating ;-)!

Comment: Also notice that `InfiniteContainer` implements that pattern internally and adds `pullToRefresh`. You can look at that code for reference